# Setting php sessions to last 1 month (or until user explicitely logs out)

Tags: session, authentication, cookies, php

I have a quick question about php sessions. If I want a session to last for on month (or until a user explicitly logs out) I change the following php.ini settings: session.gc_maxlifetime = 2592000 and session.cookie_lifetime = 2592000 from their defaults of 1440 and 0 respectively. Correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`session.cookie_lifetime` of 0 will keep the cookie till the browser restarts (basically for the entire session).

Setting your `session.gc_maxlifetime` to such a high value will mean you will have many stale sessions on your server and this might be a issue if you have large numbers of sessions - typically sessions are stored in the system's /tmp folder.  When this folder, typically on *nix machines, fills up it could cause problems on the machine - processes start locking up as they fail to create temporary files for whatever reason.  (You can change the `session.save_path` to something other than /tmp so you don't have this issue - especially on shared hosts).

Someone, though, with more experience in server configurations, may know that there are other timeouts like Apache and TCP settings that may trump this value no matter how high you create it.

I believe what you're basically asking is for a `Remember Me` feature that will allow someone to log in without having to remember their Username/Password and remember the exact state (1 month session).

The `Remember Me` feature can be implemented with a rotating authentication cookie that is set to the next token in a known series based on the user's login credentials.

The 1 month session feature can be implemented by storing the session's state in a persistent cache (file cache, database, something more elaborate like Toyko Tyrant).

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish what tumblr does. Once you log in, it seems like you are indefinitely logged in until you actually log out regardless of whether or not you close your browser etc. You don't actually "log in" again if you come back 2 weeks later, you literally stay in a logged in state for a veeeery long time. Are they just using a complicated filesystem setup to handle so many potentially stale sessions at once?

Comment: How many stale sessions could I approximately have before issues began to arise?

Answer (score 0):

If what you are asking for is a 'Remember Me' the simplest solution is:

Once a user log-in successfully, you create a random hash and store it in a cookie (on user browser) and in the database (joined to the userid)

So when the user call your script first you check the hash, if the hash is present in the databse you automatically login without asking username/password, otherwise you'll ask user/password

In the first option you "bypass" login because the hash identifies the user.
If the user explicitly logout from your site simply delete the session and reset the user hash (on db side)...

Using this method you can also set a timelimit, in cookie simply set the cookie duration, on db side add the timelimit and if a user login using an hash over the timelimit you do not allow the auth login :)

Hope this solve your question